# Cross-Compile Raspberry Pi "Kernel configuration is invalid" Error

Tags: kernel, compiling, raspberrypi, linux-headers, cross-compilation

I'm using ubuntu as a host to cross compile raspberry pi 3b+ as a target. I tried to use commands below:

```
sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C /home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/linux M=$PWD modules
```

but when I use this command it gives me error that below:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/linux'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

/home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/linux/Makefile:741: include/config/auto.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/linux/Makefile:806: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/linux'
```

in this directory:

> /home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/linux

I cloned the https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.

How can I get rid of this problem?